# Staggered Grid Item Height and Width Issue in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, staggered-gridview

I'm trying to build simple app with Staggered Grid View in Swift UI ( like in Image )

[image]

I but with my implementation Grid Items are getting overlapped.

> **How can i resolve this issue?**

[image]

Code :

**StaggeredGrid:**

```
struct StaggeredGrid<Content: View,T:Identifiable>: View where T: Hashable{
        
    // MARK: - Properties
    var content: (T) -> Content
    var list: [T]
    var columns: Int
    var showIndicators:Bool
    var spacing: CGFloat
    var columnsArray: [GridItem] = []
    
    init(list: [T], columns: Int, showIndicators: Bool = false, spacing: CGFloat = 10,@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.list = list
        self.columns = columns
        self.showIndicators = showIndicators
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.columnsArray = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: spacing), count: columns)
        
    }
    
    func setUpList() -> [[T]]{
        var gridArray: [[T]] = Array(repeating: [], count: columns)
        var currentIndex:Int = 0
        for object in list{
            gridArray[currentIndex].append(object)
            if currentIndex == (columns - 1){
                currentIndex = 0
            }else{
                currentIndex += 1
            }
        }
        return gridArray
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: showIndicators){
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: columnsArray, spacing: spacing) {
                ForEach(list,id: \.self){ columnData in
                    content(columnData)
                }
            }.padding()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Home Screen :

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = HomeScreenVM()
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                    StaggeredGrid(list: vm.arrayPhotos, columns: vm.column, content: { photo in
                        PhotoGridItem(photo: photo)
                            })
                           .padding(.horizontal)
                           .navigationTitle("Photos")
                           .searchable(text: $vm.searchText, prompt: "Search photos by title,tags")
                           .onChange(of: vm.searchText, perform: { newValue in
                               vm.loadData()
                           })
                           .onSubmit(of: .search, vm.loadData)
              
                switch vm.viewState {
                case .loading:
                     ProgressView()
                case .error(let errorMsg):
                    VStack {
                    Text(errorMsg)
                    Button(
                      "Retry",
                      action: {
                          vm.loadData()
                      }
                    )
                    }
                case .dataLoaded:
                    Text("")
                }
              
            }
                    
        }.onAppear(perform: vm.onAppear)
        
    } 
}
```

Grid Item :

```
struct PhotoGridItem: View {
    var photo: Photo
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: photo.imagePath)) { image in
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                } placeholder: {
                    Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
                }
        
                Text(photo.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                
            }.cornerRadius(10)
                .clipped()
               .background(Color.white)
                .shadow(radius: 3)
        }
        .frame(height: CGFloat.random(in: 130...170), alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use SwiftUI.Layout

Comment: Search SwiftUI flow layout

Comment: @loremipsum `Layout`  is available in iOS 16+